# Eclipse changing entire behavior when between html tags

Tags: html, eclipse, indentation, auto-indent

For some reason, my copy of Eclipse has changed the way it acts when I press enter between a set of tags or braces.

Eclipse used to do the below when pressing enter (the | represents the cursor)

```
<div>|</div>
goes to the below on enter
<div>
    |
</div>
```

Now Eclipse behaves like this:

```
<div>|</div>
goes to
<div>
|</div>
```

The same thing occurs with braces.

```
function() {|}
goes to
function() {
|}
```

and not like the old behavior below.

```
function() {
    |
}
```

I have reinstalled eclipse, I have deleted the .metadata folder from the workspace, and restarted my computer and still this doesn't fix the problem. Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Eclipse Kepler and I have similar behavior. I wonder if you previously had an Eclipse plugin installed auto-indenting for you? Maybe it was the eclipse [HTML Tidy](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/en/help/introduction.html) plugin?

Comment: It's possible. I just installed today, using the install from the eclipse.org homepage. The PHP package. If that comes with the package by default, then it would have been doing it, but I am still using the same package and not getting the original functionality.

Comment: I have the main PHP plugin installed in Eclipse. I tried to see if the issue is resolved in .php files but it isn't. One thing that is interesting is -- in the php file if I create a function the auto indentation works as you would expect, it auto indents when I hit return at the end of the first {. I checked and the same behavior occurs for Java files too. So, it would seem with the base install of Eclipse -- that web and xml (I tried with xml too) files don't get auto-indented when new elements are being created in the editors.

Comment: Alright, thanks :) I might just have to install the HTML Tidy plugin that was mentioned.

Comment: @KarlVoss did you ever find an answer to this question?  I'm seeing this same behavior in Eclipse Luna, and was wondering if you ever got to the bottom of it.

Comment: No I didn't, ended up moving to WebStorm which I prefer as an IDE now. Free with a student email if you have one too.